# Is there a good way to resolve the ambiguity between nullptr_t and pointer overloads?

Tags: c++, c++14

When using the literal `0` in C++, the compiler can't disambiguate between pointer and `nullptr_t` overloads of a function.

Code that illustrates the problem:

```cpp
struct Bar {};

void foo(Bar*) {
  std::cout << "Bar*" << std::endl;
}

void foo(std::nullptr_t) {
  std::cout << "nullptr_t" << std::endl;
}

TEST(NullPtrTest, ambiguity) {
  foo(nullptr);  // OK
  foo(0);  // ERROR
}
```

With Visual Studio 2019:

```
error C2668: '`anonymous-namespace'::foo': ambiguous call to overloaded function
message : could be 'void `anonymous-namespace'::foo(std::nullptr_t)'
message : or       'void `anonymous-namespace'::foo(`anonymous-namespace'::Bar *)'
message : while trying to match the argument list '(int)'
```

With GCC 9:

```
Test.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void {anonymous}::NullPtrTest_ambiguity_Test::TestBody()’:
Test.cpp:425:8: error: call of overloaded ‘foo(int)’ is ambiguous
  425 |   foo(0);  // ERROR
      |        ^
Test.cpp:415:6: note: candidate: ‘void {anonymous}::foo({anonymous}::Bar*)’
  415 | void foo(Bar*) {
      |      ^~~
Test.cpp:419:6: note: candidate: ‘void {anonymous}::foo(std::nullptr_t)’
  419 | void foo(std::nullptr_t) {
      |      ^~~
```

What's a good way to fix this?

Things that I don't want to do:

- Replace `0` literal with `nullptr` everywhere. There are just way too many instances in our legacy code base.
- Add an `int` or `long` (or similar) overload. Since `0` would be the only valid integer value, you would have to add a runtime check, and it would be ugly.
- Remove the `nullptr_t` overload  and check the value in the pointer overload at runtime. This works, and isn't terrible, but it prevents us from having an optimized implementation for null constants.

Thanks!

Clarifications:

- We're using C++14. However, these functions are used by a lot of code that predates C++11.
- The particular use case is to provide an optimized `constexpr` implementation when `nullptr` or `0` is used. The general pointer implementation will still have to check for null values. The `nullptr_t` overload isn't really necessary, but it would be nice.
- I'm mainly asking about this to see if there is some option that I'm not considering.

Comment: If you can arrange for `foo()` to be inlined, then your "runtime" check can actually be done at compile time.

Comment: @NateEldredge You might be right. The inlining might be sophisticated enough to make the `nullptr_t` overload pointless to begin with. But it would be nice to have a `constexpr` `nullptr_t` overload in addition to the general case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you have a `nullptr_t` overload to begin with. It only handles the case where the user passes in a literal `nullptr`. If the user passes in a `Bar*` which *happens* to be null, then it still goes to the non-null overload.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo You're right. It's just an optimization for the literal `nullptr`, which does happen a lot in this particular real-life scenario. It's not necessary at all.

Comment: To me this all sounds like a XY problem. You're asking us to fix you solution to a problem, without telling what the problem is. I think it would better to ask the original problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates were not on the exclusion list - make it a template, constrained to only accept `Bar*`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Bar {}; 

template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same_v<T, Bar>>::type foo(T*) {
  std::cout << "Bar*\n";
}   

void foo(std::nullptr_t) {
  std::cout << "nullptr_t\n";
}   

int main() {
  Bar b;
  foo(nullptr);
  foo(0);
  foo(&b);
}
```

I guess in practice your `Bar*` gets probably passed derived types, i.e., you may need a different condition in `std::enable_if`. If `foo(Bar*)` is somewhat substantial you may not want to implement in a header. However, as there is only one instantiation anyway you can put the implementation into a `.cpp` file and instantiate it explicitly or, alternatively, dispatch to an implementation function.

Comment: I don't like the idea of fixing one mistake with another. Somewhere down the line, someone will be asking "how do I get the address of a template function that only accepts one type" or something.

Comment: @PasserBy: so you tell them: `&foo<Bar>`. I don't think there is any mistake in using a constrained template here. Also: as already stated in the answer, the question didn't exclude it and, hence, this *is* an answer to the question :-)

Comment: Well, in my real case, no one will be taking the address, because the function is actually a ctor and the class is a template. Anyhow, the equivalent of `template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Bar, T>::value>> void foo(T*)` works for me. Something I didn't think of. Thanks!